# Is pointer arithmetic on allocated storage UB?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer

Let's say I want to implement std::vector without invoking any undefined behavior (UB). Is the code below invokes UB:

```
struct X{int i;};
int main(){
  auto p = static_cast<X*>(::operator new(sizeof(X)*2));
  new(p) X{};
  new(p+1) X{};// p+1 UB?
}
```

Folowing a selection of quote from the standard that may help:

**[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]**

> The pointer returned (by an allocation function) shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer to any
>   suitable complete object type (21.6.2.1) and then used to access the object or array in the storage allocated
>   (until the storage is explicitly deallocated by a call to a corresponding deallocation function).

**[expr.add]**

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
>   of the pointer operand. If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n elements,
>   the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (**possibly-hypothetical**) element
>   x[i + j] if 0<=i + j<=n; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Likewise, the expression P - J points to the
>   (**possibly-hypothetical**) element x[i − j] if 0<=i − j <=n; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

My interpretation is that allocation provides an possibly-hypothetical array of X (in C++ arrays are objects) so pointer arithmetic on allocated storage as in the exemple may not invoke undefined behavior. Or my interpretation of **hypothetical** is wrong? How could I do if the previous code snipest is UB?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't compile. Would it have been too much to expect you to add the few lines needed to make it do so?

Comment: You are the second to ask that! The previous one errased its comment, probably because when I put the link he discovered its mistake: https://godbolt.org/g/XeD783

Comment: It's not clear to me, why do you suppose that this is UB. Why would it be? `p` points to an array of 2, so `p+1` should be fine.

Comment: There is no mistake, and why can you not post the code here  as part of your question?

Comment: @geza Actualy I have no constructed an array of X, just allocated storage suitable for such an array.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: why do you ask for this? The question is completely understandable already.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Seriously I thought it was obvious that the expressions must appears in some code block, and that the "..." mean "something". I do it!

Comment: @geza It would have taken the OP literally 5 seconds to copy and paste the code, which would have made this  a better question, the kind of thing we are supposed to be encouraging.

Comment: I think that hypothetical means here "the element after the last". But I'm not sure. It should not be UB. But I let someone else answer the question, I'm far from a language-lawyer.

Comment: The way I see it, **possibly-hypothetical** applies to the element, at the location, calculated by the following expression. And can't tell if it's UB as well, since, technically speaking, you don't have array here..

Comment: This is another instance of the argument over whether the definition of 'object' (in [intro.object]) is defective, and that is still an open question as far as I know, despite multiple attempts to fix the wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically it has undefined behaviour, though we tend to ignore that. [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) should fix it properly.

The phrase "possibly-hypothetical" refers to one-past-the-end "elements" ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592194/560648)), and does not permit this case.