# What does "possibly-hypothetical" mean in the pointer arithmetic rules?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic

In the standard's specification for pointer arithmetic ([`[expr.add]/4.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2), we have:

> Otherwise, if `P` points to an array element *i* of an array object `x` with *n* elements ([dcl.array]), the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value *j*) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i + j* of `x` if *0 ≤ i + j ≤ n* and the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i − j* of `x` if *0 ≤ i − j ≤ n*.

What does "possibly-hypothetical" mean here? The passage already constrains the resulting pointer to be in range of the array. Well, including the one-past-the-end slot. Is that what it's referring to?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018409/is-pointer-arithmetic-on-allocated-storage-ub

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's the one-past-the-end "element".

> [`[basic.compound]/3:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.sentence-12) *[..]* For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), a pointer past the end of the last element of an array `x` of *n* elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element *n* of `x` and an object of type `T` that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type `T`. *[..]*